# How to interpret the ratio $\frac ab=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$ of line segments $a,b,p,q$

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Let $a,b,p,q$ line segments (e.g. $a=3\text{cm}$ and so on).
 How can I interpret or construct the ratio $
\dfrac{a}{b}=\dfrac{p^2}{q^2}$ ? 
Is this something I can find on a suitable triangle or suitable right triangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose an arbitrary segment ($\overline{P'Q'}$ in the figure), erect perpendiculars of $\overline{PP'}$ and $\overline{QQ'}$ of lengths $p$ and $q$, and construct $A$ and $B$ on $\overleftrightarrow{P'Q'}$ such that $\overline{AP}\perp\overline{PQ'}$ and $\overline{BQ}\perp\overline{P'Q}$.

[image]

Then
$$\left.\begin{align}
\frac{a}{p}=\frac{p}{c} \\[4pt]
\frac{b}{q}=\frac{q}{c}
\end{align}\right\}\quad\to\quad \frac{a}{b}=\frac{p^2/c}{q^2/c}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}$$

Here's a simple variant that constructs segment $\overline{AB}$ divided in the ratio $a:b = p^2:q^2$.

[image]

Comment: Lengths for $\mathbf{\mathit{\color{red}{a}}}$ and $\mathbf{\mathit{\color{blue}{b}}}$ given by your construction depend on the length of the arbitrary segment $P'Q'$. Please explain us how we can extend this construction to obtain given $a$ and $b$, (e.g. $a=3\text{cm}$).

Comment: The *lengths* of $a$ and $b$ depend upon the arbitrary extra length ($c$ above), but the *ratio* doesn't. Since your question was about ratios, that's all you need. ... If instead you're looking to construct specific lengths $a=p^2$ and $b=q^2$, then ... well ... you still need an additional segment to establish the "unit length" in your context; so, take $c$ to be that length (so $c=1$ disappears). (To see why this is important: A segment of length $3$cm "also" has length $30$mm; so what's its "squared" length? $9$, or $900$? Without a "unit" against which to compare, we simply can't tell.)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Interpret Ratio Case 1]

We give below two constructions that can be carried out to interpret the given ratio relationship.

$\bf{\underline{\text{Case}\space 1} :\space}$
Segaments $p$, $q$, and $a+b$ are given and we are looking for the segments $a$ and $b$, which satisfy the relationship
$$\frac{a}{b}= \frac{p^2}{q^2}. \tag{1}$$

We base our construction on Ceva’s Theorem. As shown in $\mathrm{Fig.\space 1}$, we start by drawing a line segment $AB$, the length of which is equal to $p+q$. Next, we need to draw a circle having the radius $p+q$ with the center at $A$. Then, we construct another circle having an arbitrary radius $r$ with the center at $B$, where $r \lt 2(p+q)$. The two circles intersect each other at two points. Select any one of these two points to complete the isosceles triangle $ABC$ with its apex at $A$. Mark the points $E$ and $F$ on $CA$ and $AB$ respectively such that $AE=q$ and $AF=p$. Join $BE$ and $CF$ to meet each other at point $G$. Now, construct the line segment $AG$ and extend it to cut $BC$ at $D$. A line segment $BM$, the length of which is equal to $a+b$,  is then drawn to make an arbitrary angle with $BC$. Finally, after joining the two points $C$ and $M$, a line parallel to $CM$ is drawn through $D$ to meet $BM$ at $N$.

When we apply Ceva’s theorem to the isosceles triangle $ABC$ shown in this configuration, we have,
$$\frac{c}{d}\times \frac{q}{p}\times \frac{q}{p}=1\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \frac{c}{d}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}. \tag{2}$$

Now, consider the $\triangle CBM$, where the line $DN$, which is parallel to the side $CM$, cut the other two sides $BC$ and $BM$. According to the Theorem 85 (Euclid VI. 2.), we have,
$$\frac{BN}{NM}=\frac{BD}{DC}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}. \tag{3}$$

From (2) and (3), it follows that
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}.$$

[image: Interpret Ratio Case 2]

$\bf{\underline{\text{Case}\space 2} :\space}$ Segments $a$, $b$, and $p+q$ are given and we are looking for the segments $p$ and $q$, which satisfy the relationship
$$\frac{p^2}{q^2}=\frac{a}{b}. \tag{4}$$

The method described below with the help of $\mathrm{Fig.\space 2}$ is based on Pythagorean Theorem. We start by drawing the segments $AC$ and $CD$, such that $AC=a$ and $CD=b$. The point $O$ is the midpoint of $AD$. Construct the semicircle with its center at $O$ and its diameter equals to $OD$. When the perpendicular to $AD$ is drawn through $C$, it cuts the circumference of the semicircle at $E$. Now, as shown, mark $F$ on $AC$, such that $CF=CE$. A line segment $AB$, the length of which is equal to $p+q$, is then drawn to make an arbitrary angle with $AD$. Finally, after joining the two points $B$ and $F$, a line parallel to $BF$ is drawn through $C$ to meet $AB$ at $G$.

Applying Pythagorean Theorem to three right angle triangles, we obtain,
$$DE^2 + EA^2 =AD^2 = \left(a+b\right)^2 = a^2 +b^2 +2ab, \tag{$\triangle\space DEA$}$$
$$EA^2 =AC^2 + EC^2 = a^2 + EC^2, \tag{$\triangle\space ACE$}$$
$$DE^2 = EC^2 + CD^2 = EC^2 + b^2. \tag{$\triangle\space ECD$}$$

From these three equations, it follows that $\space EC^2 = ab$. Since $\space CF = EC\space$ by construction, we have $CF =  EC = \sqrt{ab}\space$ or, in otherworld, $\space AC : CF = \sqrt{a} : \sqrt{b}.\space$ Finally, using the Intercept Theorem, we shall write,
$$\frac{AG}{GB}=\frac{AC}{CF}=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \frac{AG^2}{GB^2}=\frac{p^2}{q^2}=\frac{a}{b}.$$

Comment: +1. I always like a nice application of Ceva's Theorem. ... One nice thing here is that it lends itself to directly dividing a *given* segment in the ratio $p^2:q^2$ (as opposed to transferring results from a separate construction): Given $\overline{AB}$, construct (for convenience) *equilateral* $\triangle ABC$. Let $\bigcirc C$ of radius $p+q$ meet the side-lines at $A'$ and $B'$. Let cevians from $A'$ and $B'$ dividing the legs of $\triangle A'B'C$ into lengths $p$ and $q$ (in opposite orders) meet at $P$. Then $\overleftrightarrow{CP}$ divides original segment $\overline{AB}$ as desired.

Comment: The right-triangle construction in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118044/409) is ultimately bi-directional: Given $p$ and $q$ we can construct $a$ and $b$; given $a$ and $b$, we can construct (with the help of [Thales' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27s_theorem)) $p$ and $q$. There must be a way to reverse your Ceva construction to get $p$ and $q$ from a given $a$ and $b$, but I'm currently blanking on it at the moment.

Comment: @Blue Thanks for commenting. Actually, my construction is applicable if and only if $2\left(p+q\right) \gt a+b$. Therefore, I am going to edit my answer soon to address that shortcoming. The method, which you have suggested in your first comment, does not suffer from that drawback.

Comment: Your construction has a "shortcoming" only insofar as you state that $p$, $q$, $a$, $b$ are all known. If you look at it as a way of *constructing* some $a$ and $b$ from given $p$ and $q$ (using an arbitrary isosceles triangle with legs $p+q$), then construction is just fine.

Comment: @Blue That is exactly what I have done to rectify the shortcoming. I will post the edited answer in 4 hours time. Thanks again